# Regex: going insane?

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-negation

I have a string like this:

> Please refer to document ABC.123.1234.1234 and document CBA.321.4321

I'm running two different regex searches to separately identify two different document identifiers. The expression for the first identifer works great:

```
ABC.123.1234.1234 = \b[A-Z]{3}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\b
```

Now, the problem I'm having is with trying to extract the smaller identifier using the following expression:

```
\b[A-Z]{3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,4}\b
```

Unfortunately this returns both results, `ABC.123.1234` & `CBA.321.4321`. The only result I require the second expression to return is `CBA.321.4321`.

Comment: Added `vb.net` tag since he said it in a comment on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which regex system you are using, since they all have slightly different syntax.

What you want is a negative [zero-width lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), to make sure you get your match, and matches only count if they aren't followed by `\.[A-Za-z]{4}`.

Also, are the numbers in your data actually variable-width?  If not, it would be easier to get matches if you match `{4}` instead of `{1,4}`.  The look-ahead assertion wouldn't be as easy to implement otherwise.

You could still implement them, though.  Simply make your negative look-ahead match `\d*\.\d{1,4}` (the `\d*` being the important part to avoid partial matches).

**Edit:**

Since you're using VB.Net, here's the syntax for negative lookahead assertions in that Regex implementation:

```
(?!subexpression)
```

So your regex might become something like:

```
\b[A-Z]{3}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}(?!\d*\.\d{1,4}\b)
```

The important part to remove the longer matches, and deal with the variable width numbers is:

```
(?!\d*\.\d{1,4}\b)
```

Comment: I am using VB.net
I have change it to {4} and attempted to put \.[A-Za-z]{4} like so:
"[A-Z]{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4}\.[A-Za-z]{4}"
and still nothing .. 
Sorry im very new to regex and im finding it painfully difficult to learn more complex expressions! :-(

Comment: @DavidCampion: It takes time.  It is probably one of the lease user-friendly languages ever written :)

Comment: "[A-Z]{3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,4}(?=(\s|$))"

IT WORKED!! :-o Thank you mikel! If i had a medal i would give you one! haha thank you! 

(I accidently locked your post Mikel so had to post under your response Merlyn, sorry)

Comment: @DavidCampion: No worries.  Glad your problem got solved!  I think he deleted his post.  Sounds like he should undelete it and get awarded as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Thank you also Merlyn for coming ot my rescue so quickly :-)

Comment: "\b[A-Z]{3}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}(?!\d*\.\d{1,4}\b)"
This also worked a treat! thank you

Comment: @David No problem, I deleted it as it wasn't sure it was working reliably and didn't really have time to test it properly. Glad it's all working now though!

Answer (score 1):

If you change it to `[A-Z]{3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,4}(!\.)` it uses negative lookahead to stop matching if there's a third dot, which should give you only the result you want.

Comment: The problem with this is that `ABC.123.1234.1234` would match your regex due to the last set of digits being `{1,4}`.  The match would look like: `ABC.123.123`4.1234.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I guess how to fix it depends exactly on what format his data is in and how variable it's going to be, maybe along the lines of [A-Z]{3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,4}(?=(\s|$)) instead then.

Comment: HI Mikel, I have tried your sugguestion and now it is returning no results. Im not sure if it helps my case but the document identifier is 99% of the time wrapped in " " (space) ? is there a way to identify the require pattern but only return the result if there is a space at the start and end of the string? (then again isnt that what /bxx/b is meant to do?